# Make div visible on page load jquery

Tags: jquery

This is probably an easy solution..

I have a div that is set to display:none;

I am also using a  tag for a display to show if javascript is disabled in place to the hidden div.  I am trying to figure out how to make the display that is hidden to show but without any effects...(just have the div be there when the page loads with javascript enabled)

```
<div class="carousel-container"></div>

<style> .carousel-container {display:none;} </style>

<noscript> <div id="blah"></div> </noscript>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".carousel-container").show(10);


    });

</script>
```

I know the show effect makes it move but is there a different effect that just has the div shown when the page loads

Comment: the 'show effect' doesn't make anything move if you don't pass any parameters in it... it just appears on screen... it basically sets the css display to inline or block.

Comment: hmm it just seems glitchy when the page loads..guess thats what you trade for carrying if js is disabled..ok thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$('.target').show();
The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'block'), except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

Comment: thank you for the explanation in depth also..ill accept when i can

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this ??

You can make the div `visible` with `jquery` which you made `display:none` previously.

```
$('.carousel-container').css("visibility", "visible");
```

I hope I understood your question in right way :)